# Lubuntu equivalent for gnome-system-monitor

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, network-manager

Gnome-system-monitor shows, under resources, three things, namely CPU, Memory and Network History. Is there a Lubuntu equivalent which shows me these things? As far as I've noticed, Lubuntu has Task Manager but this only shows CPU and memory usages, without any history charts and without any network information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can install the gnome-system-monitor on Lubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-monitor
```

If you are looking for a lightweight alternative  you can use Conky:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install conky-manager
```

[image]

More possibilities you can find here http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/06/list-of-best-system-monitoring.html